# Spring Bean Map Duplicate Key

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dictionary

If I create a Spring Bean Map that has two entries with the same key:

```
<util:map id="myMap" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap">

    <entry key="key1" value="one" />
    <entry key="key2" value="two" />
    <entry key="key1" value="three" />

</util:map>
```

The third entry changes the value of "key1" from "one" to "three".

Is there a way to get it to throw an error instead? That way, in a large map bean of hundreds of entries, no duplicate keys will be accidentally used.

Comment: It's the default behaviour, unfortunately, of the HashMap class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `util:map` element does not have an attribute to specify such behavior. I would implement a `Map` subtype that throws an exception if an entry with an existing key is added to it. You can then specify that class in `map-class`.